# Saving the value of the checked check-box in an array

Tags: php, checkbox, checkboxlist

Im having a list of student names in a table , in the same table each student name has a check-box , the user will have to check the check-box to add this students in the course , so I want to save the students ID of those who have checked check-box , but it seems that I got nothing in the array !
here is the code

```
echo "<form action='S7.php' method='post'> <table width='40%' border='1' cellpadding='5'>
 <tr>
     <td>Check to add to course</td>
     <td>Student ID</td>
     <td>Student Name</td>
</tr> ";

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
 echo '
   <tr>
      <td> <input type="checkbox" name="foo['.$row['St_ID'].']" value=""> </td>
      <td>'.$row['St_ID'].'</td>
      <td>' .$row[First].' ' .$row[Last].'</td>
   </tr>';
  };

    echo "</table>";

   echo ' <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add To Course" /> </form> ';
```

Comment: You don't need echo the static html content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input must be like this:
All the checkbox must have the same name, the value is different.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="'.$row['St_ID'].'" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//Each checkbox shown next to student name has to have a value
//and in order to get the array of checked checkboxes for seleted students, 
//put `[]` next to the checkbox name.
<tr>
      <td> <input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="{$row['St_ID']}"> </td>
      <td>'.$row['St_ID'].'</td>
      <td>' .$row[First].' ' .$row[Last].'</td>
</tr>';
```